# Map that factors through a quotient but is not a homorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Say I have a group $G$, a normal subgroup $H$, and a $G$ module $M$. Suppose that that $\phi:G\rightarrow M$ is identically zero on $H$, but that $\phi$ is not a homomorphism. If we define the "kernel" (perhaps this makes sense in the category of pointed sets or something, so the quotations are unneeded)  of $\phi$ as $\ker\phi=\{g\in G: \phi(g)=0\}$, then we clearly have $H\subset \ker \phi$. Does it then follow that there exists a (perhaps not unique?) map $\psi:G/H\rightarrow M$ such that:
\begin{align*}
\psi\circ \pi=\phi
\end{align*}

I want to say that the answer is no, because if we define $\psi$ by:

$$\psi([g])=\phi(g)$$

there is a very likely chance that this is not well defined. My follow up question is then this, suppose that we know $\phi(gh)=\phi(g)$ for all $h\in H$, and $g\in G$, then does it follow that $\phi$ factors through the quotient $G/H$? Here, I also want to say no, because even though left cosets, and right cosets are equivalent because $H$ is normal, I feel like we have to check both due to the fact that $\phi$ is not a necessarily a group homomorphism.

Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: What is $A$? Also, you say $\phi$ is "identically zero", so why can't you take $\psi$ to be identically zero too?

Comment: Oh $A$ was supposed to be $M$ my bad. And $\phi$ is identically zero on $H$ not on all of $G$

Comment: Any function $f$ with domain $G$ defines an equivalence relation on $G$ by $x\sim y\iff f(x)=f(y)$. If $R$ is another equivalence relation on $G$, then $[x]_R\mapsto f(x)$ is well-defined if and only if $R\subseteq\sim$ as subsets of $G\times G$. The normal subgroup $H$ defines an equivalence relation. The "kernel" is insufficient (it is insufficient even for homomorphisms of monoids...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has more to do with functions factoring through partitions than anything else.

Given any functions $f\colon X\to Y$, the function $f$ defines an equivalence relation $\sim_f$ on $X$ by $x\sim_fy\iff f(x)=f(y)$. The equivalence relation $\sim_f$ induces partition $X/\sim_f$ on $X$, with a quotient map $\pi\colon X\to X/\sim_f$ given by $\pi(x) = [x]_{\sim_f}$, where $[a]_{\sim_f} = \{b\in X\mid a\sim_f b\}$. This partition and map has the following universal property:

**Theorem.** Let $g\colon X\to Z$ be any map. Then there exists a unique function $h\colon X/\sim_f\to Z$ such that $g=h\circ\pi$ if and only if $\sim_f\subseteq \sim_g$, when $\sim_f$ and $\sim_g$ are viewed as subsets of $X\times X$.

**Proof.** If $\sim_f\subseteq\sim_g$, then $f(a)=f(b)\implies g(a)=g(b)$. Define $h\colon G/\sim_f\to Z$ by $h([a]_{\sim_f}) = g(a)$. This is well defined, since $[a]_{\sim_f}=[b]_{\sim_f} \implies f(a)=f(b)\implies g(a)=g(b)\implies h([a]_{\sim_f}) = h([b]_{\sim_f})$. The map is unique, since $\pi$ is surjective and thus cancellable on the right: if $h\circ\pi = g =h'\circ\pi$, then $h=h'$.

Conversely, assume that there exists $h$ such that $h\circ \pi=g$. If $(a,b)\in\sim_f$, then $[a]_{\sim_f}=[b]_{\sim_f}$, so
$$g(a) = h(\pi(a)) = h([a]_{\sim_f}) = h([b]_{\sim_f}) = h(\pi(b)) = g(b),$$
so $a\sim_g b$, and therefore $(a,b)\in\sim_g$. Thus, $\sim_f\subseteq\sim_g$, as desired. $\Box$

Now, the (left) cosets of a subgroup $H$ of $G$ define an equivalence relation on $G$, $x{}_{H}\equiv y\iff xH=yH\iff y^{-1}x\in H$. In particular, a set-theoretic map $f\colon G\to X$ will factor through the quotient map $\pi\colon G\to \{xH\mid x\in G\}$ if and only if $xH=yH\implies f(x)=f(y)$.

For *group homomorphisms* there is a happy "accident": since $f(x)=f(y)\iff f(x^{-1})f(y)=e\iff f(x^{-1}y)=e$, it turns out that the equivalence relation $\sim_f$ can be completely "coded" by the kernel. This also holds for other structures such as rings and vector spaces. Hence we can take the theorem above and write it in terms of the kernel alone, as $\sim_f\subseteq\sim_g \iff \ker(f)\subseteq\ker(g)$.

But pretty soon after you leave groups and rings behind, you encounter structures where the "kernel" (even when it makes sense) no longer suffices. For example, a monoid is a nonempty set $M$ together with a binary associative operation that has an identity element $e_M$; a monoid homomorphism is a function $f\colon M\to N$ between monoids such that $f(e_M)=e_N$ and $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$. You can meaningfully define a "kernel" as
$$\ker(f)=\{m\in M\mid f(m)=e_M\},$$
but this submonoid of $M$ no longer "codes" the entire equivalence relation $\sim_f$. So in general algebra one needs to consider the whole equivalence relation (rather than just the equivalence class of $e$); these are called *congruences*, and the isomorphism theorems pass to general algebraic structures in terms of congruences.

What you have here is closer to the theorem above. Because your map $f\colon G\to M$ need not respect the group structure, you really need to check the whole equivalence relation. The fact that $H\subseteq[1]_{\sim_f}$ is insufficient to ensure that $\sim_{\pi}\subseteq\sim_{f}$ because $f$ is not a group homomorphism. So you really need to check that $xH=yH$ implies $f(x)=f(y)$ in order to "factor" $f$ through the quotient map $\pi\colon G\to G/H$.

Comment: Thank you, this is really quite obvious in hindsight, but your explanation definitely brought everything into perspective. I lost the Forrest for the trees there for a moment.

Answer (score 4):

Hint : The necessary and sufficient condition for $\phi$ to factor uniquely through the canonical map $G \xrightarrow{\pi} G/H$ is that $xy^{-1} \in H \Rightarrow \phi(x) = \phi(y)$.

In other words, each fiber of $\pi$ should be contained in a fiber of $\phi$.

Comment: I see, so for the second situation the answer is yes. In particular, if I  have a map which satisfies $\phi(gh)=\phi(g)$ for all $g\in G$, and $h\in H$, then map also satisfies $\phi(hg)=\phi(g)$, as $hg=g(g^{-1}hg)$ where $g^{-1}hg\in H$. Is this correct?